# Spaces in Mermaid

Tags: markdown, atom-editor, mermaid

I have a `.md` file saved and I am viewing it using Atom and the Mermaid Preview package. I am going off the example on their GitHub page:

```
graph TD;
  A-->B;
  A-->C;
  B-->D;
  C-->D;
```

That renders fine, but how do I add spaces the text? For example:

```
graph TD;
  A F-->B;
  A-->C;
  B-->D;
  C-->D;
```

The previewer goes blank when I put spaces in. I tried adding quotations, but that did not help.

Answer (score 25):

Try this (haven't tried it in Atom but it worked fine in VisualStudio Code with Mermaid Plugin):

```
graph TD;
  id1[A F]-->B;
  A-->C;
  B-->D;
  C-->D;
```

Instead of `id1` you can use whatever id you want.

Depending on the type of braces you use, you can change the look of the rendered Node.

- Box with round edges - `id1(A F)`
- Circle - `id1((A F))`
- Asymetric Shape - `id1>A F]`
- Rhombus - `id1{A F}`

This can be found on the mermaid [documentation site](https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid/#/flowchart)

Comment: Sadly as of now, it only works on Azure DevOps Services, not OnPremise

Comment: Unfortunately it is a dead link.

Comment: @KansaiRobot Links is updated now - i guess u could have done this by yourself too ;)

Answer (score 1):

In Typora 1.6.7 you can use HTML code in Mermaid node titles, e.g., type `Yellow&bnsp;Submarine` for a well-placed space. However, the HTML code becomes part of the node id. I found it impossible to give a node a shorthand id (as demonstrated by phifi) in addition to the title. In Typora Mermaid, the title *is* the id.