# How can I add space to block title?

Tags: gitlab, wiki, mermaid

Is it possible to add space between words in the title of a block in mermaid flowchart generation?

Basically I needed something like:
`SearchService-->items details`
but I get an error and blank flowchart when trying it.

Relates to this question: [Spaces in Mermaid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54311261/spaces-in-mermaid) that was not replied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SearchService --> itemsdetails[item details]
```

Where itemsdetails is the id and "item details" is the node label.